# Section title and bibliography

Tags: sectioning

I am trying to write my page of references, and would like to include it in my contents page, where it would be Chapter 10

However, I have included the \section{References} command, but also the \begin{thebibliography}{99} command so as to allow my references to be numbered, however this results in me having 'References' labelled twice.

Is there any way to suppress the second 'References' that is generated by \begin{thebibliography}{99}?

My code is this:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{amsfonts,amssymb,amsmath,amsthm,graphicx}
\usepackage[top=2cm, bottom=2cm, left=2cm, right=2cm]{geometry}

\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}[section]
\newtheorem{cor}[thm]{Corollary}
\newtheorem{lem}[thm]{Lemma}
\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{defn}[thm]{Definition}
\theoremstyle{remark}
\newtheorem{rem}[thm]{Remark}
\numberwithin{equation}{section}

\newcommand{\R}{\mathbb R}
\newcommand{\C}{\mathbb C}
\newcommand{\eps}{\varepsilon}
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.5}

\makeatletter
\setlength{\@fptop}{0pt}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\section{References:}
\begin{thebibliography}{99}

\bibitem{1}
    {\sc Gerald \& Wheatley},
    {\it Applied Numerical Analysis.}
    Page 165. Pearson, 2003

    \bibitem{2}
    {\sc Gerald \& Wheatley},
    {\it Applied Numerical Analysis.}
    Page 274. Pearson, 2003.

    \bibitem{3}
    {\sc Gerald \& Wheatley},
    {\it Applied Numerical Analysis.}
    Page 280. Pearson, 2003.


    \bibitem{4}
    {\sc Hoffman \& Frankel},
    {\it Numerical Methods for Engineers and Scientists.}
    Page 294. CRC Press, 2001.

    \bibitem{5}
    {\sc Hoffman \& Frankel},
    {\it Numerical Methods for Engineers and Scientists.}
    Page 296. CRC Press, 2001.

    \bibitem{6}
    {\sc Larson \& Edwards},
    {\it Calculus.}
    Page 983. Houghton Mifflin, 2009.

    \bibitem{7}
    {\sc Larson \& Edwards},
    {\it Calculus.}
    Page 983. Houghton Mifflin, 2009.


\end{thebibliography}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Could you complete your code so we can compile it?

Comment: Apologies, I have added in the extras now

Comment: Thanks. The key bit here is your class since different classes define `thebibliography` in different ways. (I should have asked for a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) as it would be better to only include the necessary code. However, I'm afraid I forgot.)

Answer (score 2):

Since you are using `article.cls`, you could use this in your preamble to patch the `thebibliography` environment:

```
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\patchcmd{\thebibliography}{\section*{\refname}}{}{\typeout{goodie!}}{\typeout{oh dear!}}
```

[image: Patched environment]

Note that it would be preferable in your code to say:

```
\section{\refname}
```

To ensure a match with the marks (used e.g. in headers) set by `thebibliography` environment. Then if you need to change it, you can just say `\renewcommend*\refname{whatever}` in one place.